# Finding Older JasperReports XSD Schemas

Tags: xsd, jasper-reports

I'm looking to find the 5.1.0 JasperReport XSD schema.  I want to do some outside manipulation of the JRXML in a language other than Java.

The current publicly available XSD at http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd currently does not validate against my current 5.1.0 JRXML.

Anyone with guidance would be helpful.  I also tried downloading the project files at sourceforge, and searching for any .XSD files, with none found.

Comment: You can find jasperreport.xsd file [here](http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jasperreports/branches/jr-5-1-0-x/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/dtds/jasperreport.xsd). Credentials: anonsvn\anonsvn

Comment: Thank you! I simply didnt know where to go.